# How to get the value "value" of a button that called a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I'm currently into a place where I call an Api with Ajax to delete a Client from a table I've. The thing is, that I've previously tried to make a check before ajax is executed, but it doesn't seem to work.

So this time, when Delete button is clicked I want to check first if the user is sure he wants to delete the client, and if true, execute the function to delete it.

The thing is, I've the id into the button like this:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value=('+value.id+') onclick="sureAboutDelete()">Delete Client</a>
</td>
```

And then in .js file I'm trying that:

```
// Check if user wants to delete Client
function sureAboutDelete(){
    console.log((event.target));
    // var id = Get the value of value attribute
    // Ask for the user if he/she is sure about deleting
    If (true){
        // delete client using ID taken
        deleteClient($id);
    } else {
        // Just close prompt
        return;
    }
}
```

When using "(event.target)" I can see all the button with the attributes, but putting "(event.target).val" or like this, I can not take the id I want.

Any suggestion?

Thanks !

Comment: Does your current code work so that the button actually has the desired ID as the value?

Comment: Yeah, the ID is inserted into the value attribute of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of:

`value=('+value.id+')` in HTML is **wrong** for several reasons

- `value` is not a valid `<a>` Element attribute. use `data-value` instead.
- You need that `data-value` beforehand, say from back-end, already embedded into your HTML
- Anchor's `type` cannot be `"button"` it's used to specify the media type in the form of a MIME type ([MDN <a>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a))
- `If` should be `if`
- pass `this` into your `onclick="sureAboutDelete(this)"`

**The result should look like: (pure JS)**

```js
function sureAboutDelete(self) {

  event.preventDefault(); // Since it's an anchor, don't scroll the page.
  
  var id = self.dataset.clientid; // Get ID vrom data-clientid attribute
  
  if( id && confirm("Delete client: "+ id) ) deleteClient( id );

}


function deleteClient( id ) {
    console.log("DELETING CLIENT: %s", id);
    // 1. DELTE FROM DATABASE
    // 2. REMOVE ANY .clientId-N element from page
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".clientId-"+ id);
    if(!elements[0]) return;
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; ++i) {
      elements[i].remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr class="clientId-2">
    <td class="text-center">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-clientid="2" onclick="sureAboutDelete(this)">Delete Client 2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="clientId-37">
    <td class="text-center">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-clientid="37" onclick="sureAboutDelete(this)">Delete Client 37</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="clientId-56">
    <td class="text-center">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-clientid="56" onclick="sureAboutDelete(this)">Delete Client 56</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

**or using jQuery:** (PS: no need to `onclick=` stuff)

```js
$(document).on("click", "[data-delete-client]", function(evt) {

  evt.preventDefault();

  // 1. retrieve client ID
  var id = $(this).data("delete-client");
  
  // 2. confirm
  if(!confirm("Really delete client: "+ id)) return; //do nothing if no confirmation, else:
  
  // 3. delete from database
  // (TODO)
  
  // 4. remove all .clientId-N elements
  $(".clientId-"+ id).fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

  <tr class="clientId-2">
    <td class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" data-delete-client="2">Delete Client 2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="clientId-37">
    <td class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" data-delete-client="37">Delete Client 37</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="clientId-56">
    <td class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" data-delete-client="56">Delete Client 56</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Perfect ! I was looking to do something like that. Thanks man. I used Jquery option and it's working and I find it's better than the thing I was trying to implement firstly.

Comment: I do not use the 4th part you entered, the ajax function for deleting the client also reloads the table with the information. But it's okay anyway.

Comment: @neoSmith great, I could not know that but might be useful for other visitors too.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, You can get the `value` attribute by using `attr()` method.

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
        var sId = $(this).attr('value');

        // Use confirm() to show a certain confirm alert message
        var bConfirmMsg = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');

        if (bConfirmMsg === true) {
            // delete client using ID taken
            deleteClient(sId);
        }
    });

    function deleteClient(sId) {
       // rest of code...
    }

});
```

Comment: Guys, when you down-vote a question or an answer, you should also state why you did it. Otherwise it's meaningless and douchie.